# Как получить данные в переменную с mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

Прошу прошения за столь глупый вопрос, но я не могу разобраться как получить данные в переменную, и так, делаю запрос:

```
$sth = $pdo->query('SELECT max(id) FROM authorized_user')->fetchAll();
print_r($sth);
```

получаю следующий результат:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [max(id)] => 48 ) )

не могу понять как получить значение 48 в переменную

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем `fetchAll` если есть **[fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php)**

```
$result = $pdo->query('SELECT max(id) as max_id FROM authorized_user')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $result['max_id'];

----

$result = $pdo->query('SELECT max(id) as max_id FROM authorized_user')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

echo $result->max_id;
```

---

А вообще в случаях когда получаете результаты функций полезно использовать алиасы ("SELECT Что-то **as** имяРезультирующейКолонки")

---

В вашем случае, когда нужно только одно значение одной колонки может быть также полезно **[fetchColumn](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)**. Тогда в `$result` уже будет лежать значение

```
$max_id = $pdo->query('SELECT max(id) as max_id FROM authorized_user')->fetchColumn();

echo $max_id;
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе, скажи пожалуйста, а какая разница между fetchAll и fetch

Comment: @иосифмахарадзе fetch - берет только одну строку ( полезно, когда в результате только одна строка получается), fetchAll - все....Возвращает массив, содержащий все строки результирующего набора)) логично))

Comment: @иосифмахарадзе в вашем случае, когда нужно только одно значение одной колонки может быть также полезно **[fetchColumn](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)**. Тогда в `$result` уже будет лежать значение

Comment: Прошу вас скиньте ссылку на материалы для изучения pdo, желательно на Русском языке, чувствую что не там и не те материалы я изучаю